# How to compile sqlite3 threadsafe in a c++ application?

Tags: c++, sqlite, compilation, thread-safety

Right now I am compiling the sqlite3 code with the following options:
`gcc -c -lpthread -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 sqlite3.c`
`g++ -o test test.cc sqlite3.o -ldl -lpthread`
And this works just fine.
But I saw in some projects, that the *define* flag `-DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1` is also in the `g++` compiler call listet. Is this required or redundant?

Comment: Inspecting the output of the preprocessor for the code you compile with and without that flag would reveal the answer for your case.

Comment: I used now instead of the `-c` and `-o` flags the `-E -dD` flags.  
There is a lot of output. What am I looking for?

Comment: differences between both variants

Answer (score 0):

The `SQLITE_THREADSAFE` symbol is needed only when compiling the SQLite code itself.
Adding it to other compiler calls is superfluous, but does not hurt.

Comment: That is [what the `SQLITE_THREADSAFE` symbol is for](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#threadsafe).